# how to avoid coffee and tea at work place

Tags: health

There is always a question which is coming in my mind how to avoid coffee and tea or put it another way how to Reduce number of times which we take coffee and tea a day . When i am in office I usually drink 7 to 8 tea per day. Each cup will 180ml . Especially developers are taking more coffee and tea they can skip meal but could not skip a cup of coffee a day . I personally believe i am getting some kind of energy when we drink any kind of hot drinks (coffee , tea, hot water , soup ) . Kindly suggest is it really good habit to drink it or does it make any side effects to our body . Please give some suggestions

Comment: Sounds like more of a health question to me.

Comment: What did you try already? How would a good answer look?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the type of question that lifehacks is for - it appears to be a mind hack along the lines of "how can I drink less alcohol?" Or "how can I train myself to use less soap?"

Answer (score 7):

This would also depend on the amount of sugar you're using per cup.

Maybe reduce the consumption by half and replace the other half by hot water, soup and herbal tea?

Answer (score 4):

The jury is still out on the effects of tea or coffee. Some studies indicate that drinking up to four 250-ml cups per day of [coffee](http://time.com/4768860/is-coffee-good-for-you/) or of [tea](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/health/news/7836681/Tea-is-it-good-or-bad-for-you.html) may actually be *good* for health, e.g. decreasing likelihood of diabetes. That said, it depends on the individual -- if it makes you jittery or your employer is concerned about excessive absence from your desk (both for input and output), you might try another beverage, such as herbal tea or soup.

(When I was a software developer, I probably had four or five cups of tea per day, and found the slight exercise of getting up to brew it also helped. However, all my employers were agreeable to this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- To avoid skipping meals, follow a schedule for the meals. If you're lucky, you have a coworker who already does that. If so, make it a habit of eating when they eat. If there's no such coworker, maybe you can be that person? If you have a work calendar with meetings etc., maybe put "lunch" there as a recurring appointment (assuming that your employer is ok with you having lunch, which they really should -- how can you work otherwise?).
- To drink less coffee/tea, make it a habit of always fetching a glas of water together with each cup of coffee/tea. Only fetch more coffee or tea after finishing both the coffee/tea and the water.
- To avoid health issues, avoid sugar in coffee/tea (and in general). If you feel that you need a beverage with sugar to have enough energy to continue working, consider eating "real food" instead of the sugar. Don't replace meals by sugar.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume for a second that the fact that you're drinking too much coffee and tea is more important than the time you're spending on getting coffee/tea.

If you have a choice of multiple places to get coffee or tea in your building, try to commit to using the one that is further away or, ideally, up a flight of stairs. The goal is to make it more annoying to get coffee or tea without making it significantly more time consuming.

Another thing you could try is keeping a bottle of water at your desk. Water is less interesting than either coffee or tea, but having a water bottle *right there* might be enough to shift your habit.